# vb.net connection string to a regular google drive

Tags: .net, vb.net, connection-string, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to link my program to my google drive but only for the database but it gives me an error message. In my program properties - settings - I have the name
"RatesConnectionString" with a value of Data Source=G:\My Drive\Program Data\Rate.mdf;User Id=myuser@gmail;Password=mypassword

I then run my program but when it gets to the part to open the database I get this error

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   HResult=0x80131904   Message=A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified)   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider   StackTrace:    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
> DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
> sqlAuthProviderManager)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
> DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
> srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
> dataTable)    at
> Pricing_Program.RatesDataSetTableAdapters.HTSTableAdapter.Fill(HTSDataTable
> dataTable) in C:\Users\mycomp\OneDrive\Desktop\Pricing
> Program\RatesDataSet.Designer.vb:line 29526    at
> Pricing_Program.FrmMenu.FrmMenu_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\mycomp\OneDrive\Desktop\Pricing Program\FrmMenu.vb:line 202
> at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
> hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I am not sure if I can or how I can link my program to a google drive database. I can get it to work on a local drive not a problem but wanted to see if I can put the program after I compile also on the drive and run it from anywhere.

Or is there a easy way to take the program I have and turn it into a web application and not a windows one?

Any help would be appreciated please

Comment: That's not how a SQL Server connection string works. See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). If you want to use a data file that is attached on demand, you need a local instance of SQL Server, usually SQL Server Express. The instance name is the data source and then you use `AttachDbFilename` to specify the data file path.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly, my string would be:
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDBFilename=G:\My Drive\Program Data;
Database=\Rate.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Comment: You would only specify an OLE DB provider in the connection string for an `OleDb.OleDbConnection` but you should be using a `SqlClient.SqlConnection`. The fact that you're getting a `SqlClient.SqlException` suggests that you already are so that connection string is not correct. You've gone too far down the page.